# Python: sorting datetime objects keeping "AM" and "PM" into account

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, strftime, strptime

This is a simplified version of what my problem is but here is the gist of it: I have a script that sorts emails by using Regex to find specific patterns. One of the items I sort by is the date an email was received. I use the datetime module to format the date string, like so:

```
    s1 = datetime.strptime(regex_obtained_str, '%B %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Now, let's say I have parsed 4 emails and these are the results from the Regex function:

```
    s1 = 'March 15, 2013 8:58:34 PM'
    s2 = 'March 15, 2013 11:10:10 AM'
    s3 = 'March 15, 2013 11:16:06 AM'
    s4 = 'April 15, 2013 12:02:04 PM'
```

Which turns into this after strftime formatting:

```
    s1 = '03/15/2013 08:58:34 PM'
    s2 = '03/15/2013 11:10:10 AM'
    s3 = '03/15/2013 11:16:06 AM'
    s4 = '04/15/2013 12:02:04 PM'
```

If I put these all in a list in random order and perform a sort() function, like so:

```
    L = [s2, s1, s3, s4]
    L.sort()
```

The output is:

```
    ['03/15/2013 08:58:34 PM', '03/15/2013 11:10:10 AM', '03/15/2013 11:16:06 AM', '04/15/2013 12:02:04 PM']
```

As you can see, the "AM" and "PM" is not being taken into account when sorting. I've looked at a NUMBER of other questions similar to this on StackOverflow, and all of them suggest changing %H to %I in the strptime()/stftime() functions to account for the 12 hour clock, but I already have done that. Can anyone please suggest how to take %p into account when sorting? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you sorting them as strings? Sort them as times, then make the strings.

Comment: @Lattyware That's probably the answer to this question.

Comment: I create one large list of emails, all of which are already strings, then I use regex to find the dates after a specific pattern in the email. To give you an example, the type of function I'm using is: L.sort(key=lambda i: i[some slice of each email], Regex_date_submitted_finder(i)) -- Sounds like you're suggesting I should just make another function that just calls strptime and no strftime, then sorts?

Comment: If the strings `s1`, `s2`, etc. are in the format `'March 15, 2013 8:58:34 PM'` as you say, and you just do `L = [s2, s1, s3, 34]` and then `L.sort()`, there's no possible way that the output could have strings in a different date format. So, which is it? (If it's the first, you have even _more_ problems—'January' > 'February', '9' > '10', etc.)

Comment: to clarify, i call strftime to reformat them

Comment: you can see the exact strftime call in the first code block

Comment: I've made edits now to make it easier for others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that you are sorting strings - Python doesn't know that these strings are times, so it just sorts them as strings (which happens to almost work).

So, the solution is, sort them when they are date objects, at this point, Python has the information it needs to sort them correctly:

```
dates = sorted([datetime.strptime(regex_obtained_str, '%B %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p') 
                for regex_obtained_str in strings])
l = [date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p') for date in dates]
```

Here using [list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to apply the formatting easily to all of the objects.

Comment: awesome! this makes sense. It's actually true, it does almost work EVERYTIME to sort by the strings, but I was reviewing the results, and OCCASIONALLY one email would be out of order

Comment: will give answer in 5 minutes (it won't let me immediately)